# Is it possible to install Mac OS after Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, macosx

I have ubuntu 15 running solo on my macbook pro. 
I'd like to install mac os as a secondary os on my computer. 
Is it possible to setup a duel boot mac after Ubuntu is already installed? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this - http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/ exept use Gparted partition editor as your starting on linux, and then do effectively the same thing but with mac being installed second intead of first